# Microstrip structures identification

Tags: rf, filter, high-frequency, microstrip, power-divider

I'm currently starting with learning how microstrip structures work.

Just for clarification: I'm talking about these here: [Microstrips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip)

In [Power dividers and directional couplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_dividers_and_directional_couplers), some basic structures are already shown.

What I am looking for are three things:

At first, a good guide on how to calculate these things and on how to come up with a good shape (some are shaped like a piece of cake, others are linear ... but the reason isn't clear to me)

From my undergraduate courses I remember the calculations for lambda/2 and lambda/4 lines etc., but these shapes are different and their function isn't becoming clear to me.

Secondly I am looking for some kind of catalogue, which shows all usually used shapes and their intended function.

In the end I am looking for informations about a shape, which looks like half of the structure in [Branch-line coupler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_dividers_and_directional_couplers#Branch-line_coupler), figure 9. The structure I'm talking about starts also at P1 and P4, but ends in the middle of the picture after the first "window" and continues in two smaller lines, like the ones going to P2 and P3 (so the second window is just missing). What is that structure and how do I come up with a structure like this?

Cheers :)

Comment: A good book will do this

Comment: i hate to say LMGTFY but did you try to search an answer for this interesting question https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/branchline-couplers